# socket通信を停止させる時にエラー：OSError: [WinError 10038] ソケット以外のものに対して操作を実行しようとしました。

Tags: python, network, socket

ソケット通信を停止させる時にエラーが出ます。
エラーを再現するために色々試して見た結果、以下のようにsleepを挟んでデータを送っていると、受信側でソケット通信を停止させる時にエラーになるようです。

**testSend.py**

```
import time
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

HOST = ''
PORT = 5000
ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1"

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

while True:
    s.sendto(str(time.time()).encode(), (ADDRESS, PORT))
    time.sleep(0.1)

s.close()
```

受信側のコードは、以下のようになっています。
GUIを立ち上げて[start]ボタンを押すとデータを受信して、200秒に1度ずつ時間をprintし
[stop]ボタンを押すと受信とprintを停止するプログラムになっています。

**testRecieve.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

class threadingGUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop_flag = True
        self.s = None
        self.thread1 = None
        self.thread2 = None

    def worker(self):
        #文字列を受け取る
        messages, address = self.s.recvfrom(8192)
        print(messages)

    def schedule(self,interval, f, wait=True):
        base_time = time.time()
        next_time = 0
        while not self.stop_flag:#接続を切るボタンが押されるまでループ
            self.thread2 = threading.Thread(target=f)
            self.thread2.start()
            if wait:
                self.thread2.join()
            next_time = ((base_time - time.time()) % interval) or interval
            time.sleep(next_time)

    def start(self):
        if not self.thread1:
            HOST = ''
            PORT = 5000

            #受信
            ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1"
            self.s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
            self.s.bind((HOST, PORT))

            self.thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.schedule,args=(1.00/200.00, self.worker, False))
            self.stop_flag=False
            self.thread1.start()


    def stop(self):
        if self.thread1:
            self.stop_flag=True
            self.thread1.join()
            self.s.close()
            self.thread1=None

    def GUI_start(self):
        root=tk.Tk()
        Button001=tk.Button(root,text="Start",command=self.start)
        Button001.pack()
        Button002=tk.Button(root,text="Stop",command=self.stop)
        Button002.pack()
        root.mainloop()

t = threadingGUI()
t.GUI_start()
```

[stop]ボタンを押すと

```
line 15, in worker
    messages, address = self.s.recvfrom(8192)
OSError: [WinError 10038] ソケット以外のものに対して操作を実行しようとしました。
```

というエラーメッセージが繰り返し表示されます。
testSend.pyからtime.sleep(0.1)を消すとこのエラーはなくなるのですが。
このsleepを残したままエラーを出さない方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sayuriさん回答とほとんど被りますが、
動作内容・原因とエラーの状況は以下になるでしょう。

- 作成したsocketが無限待ちのブロッキング型である
- scheduleスレッドの中で5ms毎にworkerスレッドを作成し、かつ終了を待っていない
- testSend.pyスクリプトは100ms毎に1回送信
- 上記により、startボタンクリック後は100ms毎に19個の受信待ちworkerスレッドが積み上がり、時間が経つごとに増えていく
- stopボタンクリックしてソケットclose&None設定後に、積み上がった受信待ちworkerスレッドが全て例外で終了する

気付かれていないもう一つの異常として、testSend.pyスクリプトを動作させずにtestRecieve.pyスクリプトだけを起動・startボタンクリック・stopボタンクリックすると、無応答状態になります。

対処としては以下の2つを両方組み込むことになるでしょう。

- socketにtimeout値(0.01～0.1秒程度?)を設定する
  あるいはノンブロッキング型に設定する(以下の例はtimeout設定)

---

```
#受信
ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1"
self.s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
self.s.settimeout(0.1)    # タイムアウト値設定を追加する
self.s.bind((HOST, PORT))
```

---

- workerスレッドの受信&print処理を例外処理で囲む
  (正常動作中でも常にtimeout等の例外が発生するので)

---

```
def worker(self):
    try:    # 例外処理を組み込む
        #文字列を受け取る
        messages, address = self.s.recvfrom(8192)
        print(messages)
    # 必要であれば以下に発生した例外種類に応じた対処を組み込む
    except:
        pass    # 例としては全てにおいて特に何もしない
```

Answer (score 1):

一般的にソケットは同期IOです。つまり

```
    def worker(self):
        #文字列を受け取る
        messages, address = self.s.recvfrom(8192)
        print(messages)
```

は受信できるまで待ち続けます。そしてこれを起動する

```
    def schedule(self,interval, f, wait=True):
        base_time = time.time()
        next_time = 0
        while not self.stop_flag:#接続を切るボタンが押されるまでループ
            self.thread2 = threading.Thread(target=f)
            self.thread2.start()
            if wait:
                self.thread2.join()
            next_time = ((base_time - time.time()) % interval) or interval
            time.sleep(next_time)
```

は受信待ちスレッドを作成し続けます。仮にループが200周すれば、受信待ちスレッドが200個作成されます。これらは送信側から200回受信しなければ完了しません。

[stop]ボタンを押すと、ソケットがクローズされるため、大量に作成された受信待ちスレッドがエラーを発生させます。

---

と状況は説明できますが、どのような処理にしたいのかがわからないので、修正案は示すことができません。